# Are our new shower faucet stems too short?

Tags: shower, faucet

We had a leaky shower stem (Price Pfister) and we had a plumber come to replace them. Now however, unlike before, the handles are completely pushed up against the metal plates when the water is off, and even when the water is on at a slow speed, and I’m concerned that when the water is off it could be pulling slightly on the stems or pipes behind because of the lack of extra room between the handle and the metal plates.

Does this sound like a problem, and is there a likely solution?

If it’s of any relevance, it also seems that it’s a lot harder to get precise temperature control at lower speeds, where turning it the slightest amount makes a bigger difference than it used to. Another observation is that there seemed to be a number of slight interruptions in water pressure, which could be noticed in the hose for the shower head looking as though it was getting occasionally tapped, which is something I didn’t notice much before.

Comment: I think you need to address this with your plumber who did the work and is familiar with the whole setup instead of a bunch of strangers.

Comment: Read the installation instructions for your  new valves, If you do not have them find them online.  Sometimes they are adjustable. We do  not have enough info to answer your question. I agree with Jack, talk to the plumber.